# hide specific area form bottom of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

i have website embedded inside iframe to use in webview application

```
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://www.medicamall.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

this is CSS Code

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#iframe {
    border:none;
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% + 200px);  
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

i need to hide specific 200px from the bottom of the iframe 
it works for me when i use height:calc(100% + 200px);   
but when scroll to the bottom of the page it's appear with scroll
how to prevent this area from shown in scroll also

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your CSS to hide the overflow to a the parent container of the iframe.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#iframe {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% + 200px);
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can see an example on my plnkr.

http://embed.plnkr.co/xFXzg7g90Itpuee6hKB9/